# how to fix the 'ERROR CODE is 1054'unknown column

Tags: mysql

```
**************************physidesk (is a database )***********************
**doctor_personal***
-----------------------
c201_user_id   c201_name
-------------------------
1                charles
2                jasvi
3                vinod
4                mahesh

**clinic_timing**
--------------------------------------------
 c201_user_id c202_weekid   c203_start_timing
---------------------------------------------
1                mon,wed        5.30pm
2                thurs          5.00pm
3                thur,friday    4.30pm

**education**
-------------------------------------
college_ID     c201_user_id  complete_year
-------------------------------------
mgruniversity   1              1963
annamalaiuniv   2              1969

**result** 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
c201_user_id  c201_name c202_weekid  c203_start_timing  college_ID complete_year
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              charles   mon,wed       4.30pm           mgruniversity 1963
2              jasvi     thur,friday   5.30pm           mgruniversity 1963
3              vinod     thurs         4.30pm           annamalaiuniv 1969
4              mahesh    mon,wed       5.00pm           mgruniversity 1963
```

i write the code like this :

```
select dp.c201_user_id
      ,dp.c201_name
      ,ct.c202_week_id 
      ,ct.c203_start_timing
      ,edu.college_ID
      ,edu.complete_year 
from physidesk.doctor_personal dp 
join physidesk.clinic_timing ct on c201_USER_ID =ct.C101_USER_ID
join physidesk.t207_education edu on ct.C101_USER_ID=edu.C101_USER_ID;
```

can any say its ocurring error

Comment: where is the table `t207_education`?

Comment: `ct.C101_USER_ID` must be `ct.C201_USER_ID`

Comment: c201_USER_ID =ct.C101_USER_ID must be dp. c201_USER_ID =ct.C201_USER_ID

Comment: sorry Jens t2017_education as its is thrid table

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
select dp.c201_user_id
      ,dp.c201_name
      ,ct.c202_week_id 
      ,ct.c203_start_timing
      ,edu.college_ID
      ,edu.complete_year 
from physidesk.doctor_personal dp 
join physidesk.clinic_timing ct on dp.c201_USER_ID =ct.C101_USER_ID
join physidesk.t207_education edu on ct.C101_USER_ID=edu.C101_USER_ID;
```

Comment: What error you are getting. Please post the complete the error with code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your edudation table is t207_education, the below query should work. During the first join you must have dp.c201_user_id instead of c201_user_id.

```
select dp.c201_user_id
  ,dp.c201_name
  ,ct.c202_week_id 
  ,ct.c203_start_timing
  ,edu.college_ID
  ,edu.complete_year 
  from physidesk.doctor_personal dp 
  join physidesk.clinic_timing ct on dp.c201_user_id =ct.c201_user_id
  join physidesk.t207_education edu on ct.c201_user_id=edu.c201_user_id;
```